# Connecting to Access database from Excel sheet - syntax error

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, ms-access

Hi I have a database with several fields and I want to insert information only into two of them. To feed this information from excel;

```
Sub testing()
On Error GoTo errorhandler

'
' testing Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'

    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strConnection As String
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Database\Path\Here\Database.accdb"

    strSql = "INSERT INTO Clients (FirstName, Initial Contact) VALUES ('Joe Sixpack', 12/1/2015);"

    cn.Open strConnection
    Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)

'    rs.Close

    cn.Close

Exit Sub
errorhandler:
    MsgBox (Err.Number & " " & Err.Description)

End Sub
```

I receive an error message "syntax error in INSERT INTO statement". But I look at the documentation of SQL on W3 schools and I see

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country) VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','Norway');
```

So the syntax looks correct. I've just verified that the table names are also correct. So where is the syntax error?

Comment: Syntax error is the space in column name which needs to be wrapped in square brackets or backticks. Also, dates need to be wrapped in pound/hashtags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you represent a date in Access

```
INSERT INTO Clients (FirstName, [Initial Contact]) 
   VALUES ('Joe Sixpack', #12/1/2015#)
```

Comment: Hi. Now it's a different error: it's asking me to enter in more fields, but according to the documentation I see, the way to only update a couple of fields is specify which fields I want to do; INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, City, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Stavanger', 'Norway'); not INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);

Comment: If there are fields that require a value, and don't have a default set, you will need to include them and a value.

Comment: how do you set it so that the fields should not require a value?